# How can I rewrite rules for subfolders?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with a simple rewrite rule in htaccess ...

My htaccess like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^company$                              /company.php?lang=en [QSA]
RewriteRule ^company/about$                        /article.php?lang=en [QSA]
```

In local, it works.
But online it doesn't work.
If I go to the URL "www....com/company/about", I have the company.php page ...
Can you explain to me what's my problem ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^company$ company.php?lang=en [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^company/about$ article.php?lang=en [L,QSA,NC]
```

Important change is disabling option `MultiViews`. Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.php` (if that exists in your system).

I have also added `L` (last) and `NC` (ignore case) flags in your 2 rules.